# How to take current date from order date to get the prospective days aging number

Tags: sql

**UPDATE:** 
I figured it out, sorry for the lack of details prior. I had to convert the date so it was showing 04/12/2017 instead of the original 20170412 and then break it down per day.

```
  SELECT
  PHPICK00.PHORDT "Days Aging",
  COUNT(DISTINCT(PHPICK00.PHPKTN)) "Total Orders"
  FROM
  PHPICK00
  WHERE
   PHPICK00.PHORDT>= 0  
  GROUP BY
   PHPICK00.PHORDT   SELECT COUNT(PHPCTL) "Orders",                                  
  CASE When                                                     
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),6,2)||'/'||                                                       
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),8,2)||'/'||                                                       
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),2,4) = current date -1 days then '1 Day'
  when                                                          
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),6,2)||'/'||                                                       
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),8,2)||'/'||                                                       
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),2,4) = current date -2 days then '2 Day'
  when                                                          
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),6,2)||'/'||                                                       
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),8,2)||'/'||                                                             
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),2,4) = current date -3 days then '3 Day'      
  when                                                                
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),6,2)||'/'||                                                             
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),8,2)||'/'||                                                             
   SUBSTR(DIGITS(PHSTDT),2,4) = current date -3 days then '4+ Days'
   else 'Ship Start Date Not Yet Met' END AS "Days Aging"                                       

  FROM PHPICK00                                                       
  WHERE PHPSTF < '90' AND PHSTDT > 0
```

---

I am trying to have the return statement show the days aging per order. All I am able to retrieve is date as the generic form "20170412", whereas, I am wanting it to output "1", "2", "3" etc.

I'm very new to SQL! Hope this is an easy fix.

```
SELECT
  PHPICK00.PHORDT "Order Date",
  COUNT(DISTINCT(PHPICK00.PHPKTN)) "Total Orders"
FROM PHPICK00
WHERE PHPICK00.PHORDT = PHPICK00.PHORDT - GETDATE()
GROUP BY PHPICK00.PHORDT   
ORDER BY PHPICK00.PHORDT DESC
```

Comment: Date functions differ for each RDBMS so we'll need to know which databse you are using (mysql is not postgres is not sql server)

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Based on `GETDATE()` I'd guess SQL Server.  amirite?

Comment: @Hogan: but then the `||` for string concatenation would be wrong.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. Putting a column name in parentheses is useless. It should be `COUNT(DISTINCT PHPICK00.PHPKTN)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this -- kinda hard to tell tho.  Might want to be clearer in your quesiton.

```
DATEDIFF(day,PHPICK00.PHORDT,GETDATE())
```